# Clearing a float on an element makes it jump below a non-floated element

Tags: css, css-float

This is hard to explain, so let me just give you a link: http://jsbin.com/izinoy/6/edit#html,live.
You can easily see the unwanted behaviour: the box "six" jumps below the left navigation, because I applied a clear: left.

But I don't want this to happen, obviously. I don't know why this happens, cause the navigation is not floated, so why does it jump below navigation and how can I "fix" this?

---

EDIT:
**There's a problem with my question**. I don't know how this happened :-/, but in the question I said that navigation is not floated, even though *it is!* That's why the float didn't make sense to me. I overlooked this "tiny" detail. Yes, it's now obvious why the box "six" jumps below the navigation.

Comment: What is the desired effect? I don't understand.

Comment: Here is a good read concerning css: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/concepts

Comment: If you remove `clear:left;` all the content boxes sit together... is this what you want?  What is the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.box` selector defines `float: left`. This property causes the element to float.

About `clear:left`, let me quote https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/clear:

> The clear property specifies whether an element can be next to
>   floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared)
>   below them.
>
> ***left***: Element is moved down to clear past left floats.

Remove `float: left` if you want to align all boxes vertically. Remove `clear:left` if you don't want the `div` elements to shift down.